# file input not working for logstash (.kibana index)

Tags: logstash

New to logstash and having problem with it processing log files.

I am running it on Windows Server 2008 R2 with IIS 7.5. ELK versions:
ElasticSearch v 1.4.4
Logstash v 1.4.2
Kibana 4.0.1

I can get simple cmd line input working.
Logstash.conf:

```
input { stdin {} }
output {
  elasticsearch { host => localhost }
  stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Then run logstash from ../bin using:

```
.\logstash agent -f logstash.conf
```

Whatever I type then gets added to logstash-2015-03-18 document.

However, I am wanting logstash to process log files from my own application, which will be copied (until I have ELK working 100%) to E:/tmp/logs

So I have changed logstash.conf to:

```
input { 
  file { path => "E:\tmp\logs\*.log" }
}
```

I have used nssm.exe to configure the logstash service as follows:

```
Path: E:\LogStash files\logstash-1.4.2\logstash-1.4.2\bin\run.bat
Startup dir. : E:\LogStash files\logstash-1.4.2\logstash-1.4.2\bin
Dependencies: elasticsearch-service-x64
```

run.bat is

```
logstash.bat agent -f logstash.conf
```

**So, what is the problem?**
When I run the service I am not seeing a new index in ElasticSearch (I use DHC Chrome Plugin). Only index is .kibana (I presume this is for Kibana itself ?!).

Is there something wrong with above or can I output the file processing to a file to debug?

Regards
Craig

PS. I have deleted the .sincedb* files.

Comment: Unless you set `start_position => beginning` for a file input (and Logstash hasn't seen the file before) it'll only tail the files. Are you actually adding data to the files so that the tail operation results in any new lines to process?

Comment: So add start_position => "beginning" after file { path => "E:\tmp\logs\*.log" } and before closing } for input ?

Comment: Add it before the closing brace for the file input, so `file { path => "..." start_position => beginning }`. Again, this only makes a difference for new files that Logstash hasn't been before. To have it treat seen files as unseen, delete the sincedb files. Not sure where those are stored on Windows.

Comment: I deleted the .sincedb* files (located in users home dir) and then added a couple of new files, but they are still not being processed.  I know it works because I also started another process via the command line which takes stdin as input and that gets sent to elasticsearch.

Comment: You can try enable verbose logging with `--verbose` or even `--debug` to get more clues about the problem. Could be a typo in the filename pattern, insufficient permissions, or something else.

Comment: There is also a bug related to Windows and file globs: https://logstash.jira.com/browse/LOGSTASH-429

Comment: So, if I use the proper path to ISS logs (C:/inetpub/logs/LogFiles/W3SVC*/*.log) then it works fine. It just doesn't work to a folder on my E: drive.

Answer (score 1):

To process log files in windows :

1) Use setting :

```
input {
  file {
   path => "D:/ELK STACK/<...>.log" 
   start_position => beginning // to prevent tailing
   sincedb_path => "/dev/null" // set sincedb path
  }
}
```

2) Check whether you have given correct file path

3) If still it doesn't read from file, try

```
logstash agent -vv -f test.conf (--v highest verbosity level)
```

if you are getting _discover_file_glob error it means your path is incorrect.

It might be bcse of following issues too :

1) logstash assumes each event to be one line. So it looks for "\n" at the end of each line. So add an empty line at the end of file.

2) lack of appropriate file permission